# WebStorm: set "npm ci" as default action

Tags: npm, dependencies, webstorm, npm-install

I'm using WebStorm and when my dependencies need to be updated I get a notification with a button "run 'npm install'" (see picture below).

[image]

Question : is there a way to change the action of this notification button to `npm clean install` (npm ci) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible right now.

You may be interested in the following tickets (star/vote/comment them to get notified on any progress):

- [WEB-44244](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44244) -- Option for making `npm install` button actually run `npm ci`
- [WEB-42233](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42233) -- Node and npm: Support running `npm ci` when there are changes to the package.json
- [WEB-56353](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56353) -- Suggest to run `npm ci` in "More actions..."